# Jquery change display css doesn't work fine

Tags: jquery, css, display

I have the next code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
            debugger
            $('#comp').ready(function() {
                $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
                $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
                $('#QV103').css("display", "none");
            });

            $('#comp').on('click', function(event) {
                debugger
                $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
                $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
                $('#QV103').css("display", "none");  
            });
            $('#mes').on('click', function(event) {
                debugger
                $('#QV101').css("display", "none");
                $('#QV102').css("display", "inline");
                $('#QV103').css("display", "none");

            });
            $('#hora').on('click', function(event) {
                debugger
                $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
                $('#QV101').css("display", "none");
                $('#QV103').css("display", "inline");

            });
            debugger

        });
</script>
```

The problem is that the script show the element idQV101, but when I click the other buttons these doesn't show anything conversely in the web console the css change correct but in the screen doesn't show.
I don't want use hidden because appear a ugly gap in the screen. because under these elements there is others because under these elements there is other elements

it is the html code the values #QV... its becaus i insert qlik code and show a chart

> Comparativa
>                       Consumo mes
>                       consumo hora
>                       Consumo dia

```
                <div id="QV101" class="col-md-12 qvobject">    
                </div>
                <div id="QV102" class="col-md-12 qvobject">       
                </div>
                <div id="QV103" class="col-md-12 qvobject">

                </div>

            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div id="QV114" class="col-md-2 qvplaceholder">

                </div>
                <div id="QV115" class="col-md-2 qvplaceholder">
```

```
                </div>
                <div id="QV117" class="col-md-2 qvplaceholder">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thank you

Comment: better add or remove class instead of straight forward setting css

Comment: And if `the web console the css change correct but in the screen doesn't show`, so your issue isn't regarding your posted code but about CSS rule or HTML markup or... Provide MCVE

Comment: i don't know, because if i delete  this                      $('#comp').ready(function() {
                $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
                $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
                $('#QV103').css("display", "none");                });                                                                                      the code work well but these isn't that i want,  thank you

Comment: Can you share you HTML code as well? Also, if the clickable/affected elements are of same type, you can use a class selector to just hide all the elements on click of any element while showing just the clicked element instead.

Comment: i share my html code thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet showing that your code works correctly:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  debugger
  $('#comp').ready(function() {
    $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
    $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
    $('#QV103').css("display", "none");
  });
  $('#comp').on('click', function(event) {
    debugger
    $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
    $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
    $('#QV103').css("display", "none");  
  });
  $('#mes').on('click', function(event) {
    debugger
    $('#QV101').css("display", "none");
    $('#QV102').css("display", "inline");
    $('#QV103').css("display", "none");

  });
  $('#hora').on('click', function(event) {
    debugger
    $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
    $('#QV101').css("display", "none");
    $('#QV103').css("display", "inline");

  });
  debugger
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="comp">comp</button>
<button id="mes">mes</button>
<button id="hora">hora</button>
<div id="QV101">QV101</div>
<div id="QV102">QV102</div>
<div id="QV103">QV103</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but where is the difference between your code and my code?

Comment: but when i try it doesnt work, it is extrange, y think that it can be because QV... is  a java script element make for qlik app?. thank

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#QV101').addClass('show');
$('#QV101').siblings(':not(button)').addClass('hide')



$('#comp').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#QV101').siblings(':not(button)').removeClass('show');
  $('#QV101').addClass('show');
  $('#QV101').siblings(':not(button)').addClass('hide');
});
$('#mes').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#QV102').siblings(':not(button)').removeClass('show');
  $('#QV102').addClass('show');
  $('#QV102').siblings(':not(button)').addClass('hide');
});
$('#hora').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#QV103').siblings(':not(button)').removeClass('show');
  $('#QV103').addClass('show');
  $('#QV103').siblings(':not(button)').addClass('hide');

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="QV101">1</div>
<div id="QV102">2</div>
<div id="QV103">3</div>


<button id="comp">comp</button>
<button id="mes">mes</button>
<button id="hora">hora</button>
```

1. added `:not(button)` to exclude buttons (can also use sibling(div))
2. use `.siblings()` to get all div.
3. add/remove the class depending on the button clicked

Comment: i don't try your answer because i found the middle solution. but thanks for your asnwer too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach that I have described in my comments above. This will reduce the lines of code & easy to maintain. The JSFIddle link is given below:

The updated Code is as follows:

```
$(function(){

    $('#comp').ready(function() {
    $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
    $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
    $('#QV103').css("display", "none");
  });

  $('#comp').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.toggleDiv').hide();
    $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");    
  });
  $('#mes').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.toggleDiv').hide();    
    $('#QV102').css("display", "inline");
  });
  $('#hora').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.toggleDiv').hide();    
    $('#QV103').css("display", "inline");
  });

});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/kseqvbuv/)

Comment: Can you please let me know the reason why this approach is not preferred/ does not work?

Comment: becaus i copy the code and nothing happened, but i'm looking that whit toggle is possible

Comment: Did you copy the entire code from Fiddle link? For the code to work, you need to apply the class to the divs as mentionend in Fiddle link. If there is no class applied to the divs, the code will not work.

Comment: i see now, but the real problem was that the chart in qv... don't refrexh well, but i solve the problem in my answer, altought thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem  in part this is the code

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(window).load(function(){
> debugger
> ```

```
 $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
 $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
 $('#QV103').css("display", "none");

$('#comp').on('click', function(event) {
 debugger
 $('#QV101').css("display", "inline");
 $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
 $('#QV103').css("display", "none");  
});
$('#mes').on('click', function(event) {
debugger
 $('#QV101').css("display", "none");
 $('#QV102').css("display", "inline");
 $('#QV103').css("display", "none");

});
$('#hora').on('click', function(event) {
debugger
 $('#QV102').css("display", "none");
 $('#QV101').css("display", "none");
 $('#QV103').css("display", "inline");

});
debugger
});
    </script>
```

now the problem is that the qv is a qlik chart and this doesn't show the first time this show when I do scroll few later time.
the problem not is the code is the chart, it was create for outside app Qlik,

Thanks for all answers